# EC2 login with Tableau

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, tableau-api

I'm trying to login to my EC2 instance from Tableau. I have the postGresql driver installed on my Windows machine(w/ Tableau installed) and want to login to my EC2 instance.

From Tableau, it asks me for...
Server
Port
Database
Username
Password

What is my username/password that I have to login with? I can ssh into my EC2 instance no problem but that is using my .pem file. I'm a totally newbie so can someone help with my schoolboy question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give Tableau the location of the database on your EC2 instance. The username and password that it is asking for are the credentials for your database *not* your EC2 instance.

Also, you will need to make sure that your Security Groups settings allow Tableau Desktop to directly connect to the database you have running in EC2. The default EC2 Security Group is as follows:

*A default security group is named default, and it has an ID assigned by AWS. The following are the initial settings for each default security group:*

- *Allow inbound traffic only from other instances associated with
  default security group*
- *Allow all outbound traffic from the instance*

So if you are running Tableau Desktop outside of AWS then you will have to specifically allow that traffic through.